# Custom field validation in Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, product

I would like to create a Woocommerce product with an additional text input field which checks if the value entered is unique to that field otherwise outputs a message.

In other words if I enter "dave" and "dave" has been submitted by a different user then I cant proceed with the purchase.

Any help would be much appreciated,
I dont know where to start on this one.

Comment: To the community: This is **NOT too broad** … sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done **in a very simple way** with 3 small hooked functions:

- The 1st one, add the custom input text field before add to cart button in single product pages
- The 2nd one make the validation, checking that is a unique value
- The 3rd one save the value as product meta data in the array of existing values after validation

The submitted value will be verified for the current product...

The code:

```
// The product custom field before add-to-cart button - Frontend
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'action_before_add_to_cart_button' );
function action_before_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;

    echo '<div>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'custom_unique', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('The label name'),
        'placeholder'   =>__('Please enter …'),
        'required'      => true,
    ), '' );

    // For test: displaying existing submitted values (commented - inactive)
    // print_r( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_custom_unique_values', true ) );

    echo '</div><br>';
}

// Field validation (Checking)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_add_to_cart_validation', 20, 3 );
function filter_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {

    // Get the custom field values to check
    $custom_unic_values = (array) get_post_meta( $product_id, '_custom_unique_values', true );

    // Check that the value is unique
    if( in_array( $_POST['custom_unique'], $custom_unic_values ) ){
        $passed = false ; // Set as false when the value exist

        // Displaying a custom message
        $message = sprintf( __( 'The value "%s" already exist, try something else…', 'woocommerce' ), sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_unique'] ) );
        wc_add_notice( $message, 'error' );
    }
    return $passed;
}

// Save the new unique value in the array of values (as product meta data)
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'action_add_to_cart', 20, 6 );
function action_add_to_cart( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ){
    if( isset($_POST['custom_unique']) ){
        // Get the array of existing values
        $custom_unic_values   = (array) get_post_meta( $product_id, '_custom_unique_values', true );
        // append the new value to the array of values
        $custom_unic_values[] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_unique'] );
        // Save the appended array
        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_custom_unique_values', $custom_unic_values );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]